# How to specify version ranges in Conda environment.yml

Tags: python, conda, environment, miniconda

Is it possible to specify version ranges in an environment.yml file for Conda packages?

The [official documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually) mentions a few examples that rely on the asterisks (*) and I am wondering if that is the only feature or whether Conda supports other more sophisticated version ranges such as those [supported by npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#using-semantic-versioning-to-specify-update-types-your-package-can-accept).

For example, is it possible to install any patch version that is higher or equal to `1.2.3` (e.g., `1.2.10` would be fine but `1.3.0` is not)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think/assume that the syntax specifying versions is the one documented at [Package match specifications](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html#package-match-specifications).

So you would write `- numpy >=1.2.3,<1.3` (space after numpy, no space after the comma - not tested).

BTW, I couldn't find any documentation describing the structure of the environment file `environment.yml`. [creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) refers to [Creating an environment file manually](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually) and vice-versa.

Comment: this does not work... anymore?

Answer (score 13):

You could write something like:

```
dependencies:
  - numpy>=1.2.3, <1.3
```

Comment: Should it not be enough to write: `numpy=1.2`?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer I think you meant `numpy!=1.2` – it's not exactly the same, since `!=` would avoid everything `1.2.x` but here they want to include all `1.2.x` starting with `1.2.4`. But you could be verbose with something like `numpy!=1.2.0,!=1.2.1,!=1.2.2,!=1.2.3` to the same effect.

Comment: this does not work... anymore?