# Conda dependency range specifiction: ResolvePackageNotFound

Tags: python, anaconda, dependencies, conda, environment

I have an `environment.yaml` with this content (MWE)

```yaml
name: the-env
dependencies:
  - pandas>=1.5.0,<2.0.0
```

I run `conda env create -f environment.yaml`

I get

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - pandas[version='>=1.5.0,<2.0.0']
```

Why.

Docu is useless for my question... or I don't find the right section, and [the answers to this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847688/how-to-specify-version-ranges-in-conda-environment-yml) also say this format is valid (I generate the actual `environment.yaml` with `poetry2conda`).

Was there a change? What is the correct range syntax?

btw I run `conda 22.9.0`.

Comment: presumably there is no pandas in that range for the os/python version ... use a more recent (or less recent maybe) version of conda/python

Comment: Yes there is. For example doing `conda install "pandas<2.0.0"` can be resolved.

Comment: What is the platform? What channels? Only **conda-forge** channel has 1.5+.

Comment: @merv How does that matter? Doing `conda install "pandas<2.0.0"` works. What fails is `conda install -f evironment.yaml`. Should the latter not work if the former works, since the latter specifies a version range, which the former satisfies?

Comment: The channels definitely matter and are unspecified in the YAML shown. Currently, only **conda-forge** builds `pandas` in the `>=1.5.0` range.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, only Conda Forge provides any builds satisfying `pandas>=1.5.0`. So, the YAML should use:

```yaml
name: the-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - pandas>=1.5.0,<2.0.0
```

> *"Should the latter not work if the former works...?"*

`pandas>=1.5.0,<2.0.0` is a subset of `pandas<2.0.0`, so the former being solvable entails that the latter will also be solvable (e.g., `pandas=1.5.0` satisfies both), but the latter being solvable does not entail the former can be solved (e.g., `pandas=1.4.0` only satifies `<2.0.0`).